# what is the diference between RUP and 2TUP

Tags: uml, rup

what are the diffrences between RUP and 2TUP?
Does someone has any practical explanation of the relation between these two interesting concepts. thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is non-coding question about development methodologies and processes. Search for your answer on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site

Comment: Personally I haven't heard of Two Step Unified Process until now. Even the Rational Unified Process is (probably) dead. What exactly do you need to find out and why?